# Focus and Tab Index for drop down menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, focus, tabindex

Bit of a wierd one, I have been making a css and html only drop down menu on click with focus and tab index and run into a problem.

The links in my drop down menu don't work as when clicked the menu closes.

Has anyone run into this before I will show you the fiddle so you know what I mean in the example the link to google doesn't work as the menu closes when the link is clicked.

Html:

```css
/* Css */

 li.collapse > a{
   cursor: pointer; 
   display: block;
 }
li.collapse:focus{ 
  outline: none;
}
li.collapse > div.inside{ 
  display: none;
}
li.collapse:focus div.inside{
  display: block; 
}
div.inside:focus{ 
  display: none;
}
div.inside:hover{
  display:block;
}
div.inside{}
```

```html
 <li class=collapse tabindex="1">Click here for drop down links
    <div class="inside">
      <a href=http://www.google.co.uk>google</a> <br>
    </div>
</li>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/znq7mz1d/

Is there any way around this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Or can someone explain what causes it to stay open while clicking within the div but clicking a link within the div it closes?

Comment: From a quick glance it looks as though it's loosing focus when you try to click the link.

Comment: @Jishnu V S Thanks for the edit! 

Shannon Young, Thanks for the response, do you know if there is a way to maintain the focus?

Comment: we can do with this simple Jquery,

Comment: if we do with this `focus` method when we click the other menu `focus` will be out the main menu.. thats why the child menu disappearing

Comment: @JishnuVS I'm not entirely sure what you mean? Could you show me on fiddle? I have tried making the sub menu a different tab index, also tried focus for the child menu (div.inside) with no luck. Thanks alot for all your help!

Comment: I have yet to see a pure CSS dropdown menu behave the way that you want it to. You're going to have to add a bit of JS.

Comment: @hungerstar aw that's annoying! Thanks for the answer though! Would it be complicated JS or hard to integrate into what I already have? I am a complete beginner at JS.